# make a beter code in python for this qustion

Tags: python

hello friends i'm  not so skill in python but i thinks its a good programing language
my secound code has not very serious peroblem see:

```
# frist practicing :compoter can you guess??
import random
t=True
d=True
randomcomputer1 = random.randint(1, 100)
print(randomcomputer1)
while t==d :
    n=input("biger or correct or smaller ?")
    if (n=="b"):
        n=False
        randomcomputer1=random.randint(randomcomputer1+1, 100)
        print(randomcomputer1)
    elif(n=="s"):
        n=False
        randomcomputer1=random.randint(1,randomcomputer1-1)
        print(randomcomputer1)
    elif(n=="c"):
        print ("good job")
        d=False
    else :
        t=False
        print("oh you should enter b or c or s!!! for order biger or correct or smaller")
```

i like to coding very well
my problems :(my number is 68)
program give my 43 and i say b after says 77 and i say s but i like to computer says a number between 43 and 77 but says 33(this is a examples )so i think in this program for this problems around 1 hours but i dont have an idea please help me what can i do for this code thats going correct and beter?
please help me thanks for every thing (Note Optimize this code)

Comment: FYI, if the code works, there is another Stack Exchange site called [codereview.se] where you can post working code and have people tell you ways to improve it.

Comment: The `t` and `d` variables seem unnecessary. To continuously loop, you can use `while True:` and to end the loop then the user enters "c" you can issue `break` command.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp OP doesn't successively (recursively) narrow the interval, so this might work given enough attempts -- but it could be very (very!) many attempts...

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to keep a min value and a max value and guess between those two. Then you update those value inside your function depending on the condition. This should do the trick.

```
import random

min_value = 0
max_value = 100

while True:
    randomcomputer1 = min_value + (max_value - min_value) // 2
    print(randomcomputer1)

    n = input("biger or correct or smaller ?")
    if n == "b":
        min_value = randomcomputer1 + 1

    elif n == "s":
        max_value = randomcomputer1 - 1

    elif n == "c":
        print("good job")
        break
    else:
        print("oh you should enter b or c or s!!! for order biger or correct or smaller")
```

Comment: `min_value = randomcomputer1 + 1` (and `max_value = randomcomputer1 - 1`).  I would have chosen the next guess to be `min_value + (max_value - min_value) // 2`, i.e. the middle of the interval.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was just trying to put a ceiling and a flooring to the guess, but the code can be optimized a lot more. I will edit for your changes.

Comment: Randomly guessing in the interval will, on average, have the same performance as selecting the middle (the average of possible choices). The performance of an individual run would be less predictable though, which is why one normally wouldn't do it.